# mypy raises Cannot assign multiple types to name

Tags: python, mypy

This looks like a bug in mypy and a false positive. Below is a standard case where we pass an inherited class to a function to process it. Very explicit and simple code however mypy fails to parse it and forces us to declare the type before if statement like in c++

the code below raises:

`25: error: Cannot assign multiple types to name "syncer" without an explicit "Type[...]" annotation  [misc]`

```
from typing import Type


class Base():
    pass


class A(Base):
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


def executeSync(syncer: Type[Base]):
    pass


something = True

if something:
    syncer = A
else:
    syncer = B

executeSync(syncer)
```

we need to change it to:

```
something = True

syncer: Type[Base]

if something:
    syncer = A
else:
    syncer = B
```

I feel like the extra declaration in this case is totally unnecessary. Is there a way to change mypy configuration to avoid this? pycharm seems to be more relaxed and is not complaining about it.

Comment: `the extra declaration in this case is totally unnecessary` mypy treats the first reachable assignment as the type that bound for the rest of the code. If you discard this behaviour, you would be allowed to arbitrarily assign values to `syncer`, you'll *never* get a type error upon assignment, and `syncer` might as well be `Any`. (also, `syncer` should be annotated as `type[Base]` not `Base`)